# Can alloca () be replacement for auto pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation

alloca () is used to allocate memory from stack which is automatically freed on reaching the end of the scope. At the same time, auto pointers in C++ ensures the dynamically allocated memory from heap is automatically freed during stack winding.

Would it be right to say that alloca() provides similar functionality of automatic reclaim as provided by auto pointers?

Comment: Your premise is wrong. Memory allocated by `alloca` is freed at the end of the surrounding *function*.

Comment: `alloca` is not portable, it's not part of neither the C, the POSIX nor any other standards, it's compiler dependent. Use of it should be avoided. And of course, even if the memory will be unallocated "automatically" at the end of the function, it will not (just like `malloc`) call any constructor or destructor on allocation/deallocation.

Answer (score 2):

No, not at all, that would be entirely wrong. The purpose of smart pointers in C++ (`unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` and the old and deprecated `auto_ptr`) is to own allocations of memory on the free store, i.e. objects allocated with `new` (though there's some flexibility). The vendor-specific `alloca` allocates memory (not objects) on the call stack, not on the free store.

The closest analogue for `alloca` in a standard is the *variable-length array* of C, but C++ doesn't even have that. And even then the semantics are different, since names in C and C++ are scoped, but the semantics of `alloca` are not systematically tied to scopes (but rather to *functions*). If you will, think of `alloca` as providing "local variables of dynamic size", but that analogy has many pitfalls.